# Jenkins Terraform apply

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to update a component in aws. But when I do **terraform apply dev.plan** , it is actually trying to create instead of update and then throw **Error creating Step Function State Machine: StateMachineAlreadyExists: State Machine Already Exists**

Need solution for why "terraform plan -target=module.orchestrate -input=false -out dev.plan" does **6 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy** instead of **6 to change** Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you managing Terraform's state?

Comment: I'm not sure.. What does that mean? I use terraform refresh, then terraform plan and then terraform apply

Comment: You should read about how [Terraform uses state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/index.html) to track what resources it is managing and then how you can share it by storing it in a remote backend. If you have a specific question after that then if you edit your question to show what you've tried then someone should be able to help you with that specific issue.

Comment: This does sound like the state is not being retained between JP stages and/or pipelines. If the state is a local file and the workspace is ephemeral, then this is a likely side effect.